# Unexpected results in Powershell while creating a string for base64 basic auth tokenization

Tags: powershell, rest, basic-authentication

I'm trying to call a jira REST service using PowerShell following the instructions [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/), where the basic auth string username:password of fred:fred results in a hash of ZnJlZDpmcmVk.

I have not been able to recreate that value using a powershell ps1 script and am looking for help.

My function is spitting out "fred fred:", which obviously results in a different hash- ZnJlZCBmcmVkOg==
However, my operations seem to work when ran directly in the shell.

My function:

```
function hash-64($user,$password){
    $u=[string]$user
    $p=[string]$password
    $all="${u}:${p}"
    write-host $all
    $base64AuthInfo = [convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($all))
    return $base64AuthInfo
}
```

Exection:

```
PS H:\> hash-64('fred','fred')
fred fred:
ZnJlZCBmcmVkOg==
```

From Shell:

```
PS H:\> $u='fred'
PS H:\> $p='fred'
PS H:\> $shell_all="${u}:${p}"
PS H:\> write-host $shell_all
fred:fred
PS H:\> $base64AuthInfo = [convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($shell_all))
>>
PS H:\> $base64AuthInfo
ZnJlZDpmcmVk
```

Notice in the shell the string is correct AND the hash matches the expected result. As you may notice in the function i'm grasping with casting as a solution (not) and I've tried various tricks from other posts all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing an array to hash-64. Try calling it with `hash-64 -user 'fred' -password 'fred'` or `hash-64 'fred' 'fred'`

Comment: Yes! It makes obvious sense now.PS H:\> hash-64 -user 'fred' -password 'fred'
fred:fred
ZnJlZDpmcmVk